# How to bind a ko.obersavableArray that is nested in an object

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have my *knockout* page hub, and I need a `ko.obeservableArray` nested in a `ko.observable` object, this is where I define them:

```
 function IncomeDeclarationHub() {
    //data comes from a ajax call. 
    self.myIncomeDeclarationViewModel = ko.observable(new IncomeDeclarationViewModel(data));
 }

 function IncomeDeclarationViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.retentionAmount = ko.observable();
    self.taxableMonth = ko.observable();
    self.incDecDetGroViewModels = ko.observableArray();
    if (data != null) {
        var arrayLenght = data.IncDecDetGroViewModels.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLenght; i++) {
            var myObject = new IncomeDecDetGroViewModel(data.IncDecDetGroViewModels[i]);
            self.incDecDetGroViewModels.push(myObject);
        }
    }
 }
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
  <span class="label">
       Retention Amount
  </span>
  <input data-bind="value: myIncomeDeclarationViewModel.retentionAmount" />
  <table>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: myIncomeDeclarationViewModel.incDecDetGroViewModels">
          ...
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

Ok so the thing is that `incDecDetGroViewModels` never gets populated, I used to have that `ko.obersableArray` outside the object, and it worked fine, now that I inserted it in my object `myIncomeDeclarationViewModel` is not populating the html table. Do I need to call it in a different way at the `data-bind`

Comment: Have you considered not making the ViewModel itself observable?  Typically you would want the individual properties of the view model to be observable, not the view model itself since the view model itself doesn't change.

Comment: @xDaevax and how can I access the properties from the view?

Comment: Properties of a view model can still be accessed from a view without the viewmodel iteself being observable as long as the properties are observable.  Here is some knockout I was working on for fun where I do this type of thing: http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/aVpUJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myIncomeDeclarationViewModel` is an observable, so you have to unwrap it to access it's properties. Add parenthesis to unwrap it (access the observable's underlying value) like this:

```
<span class="label">
   Retention Amount
</span>
<input data-bind="value: myIncomeDeclarationViewModel().retentionAmount" />
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: myIncomeDeclarationViewModel().incDecDetGroViewModels">
      ...
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Here's a working jsFiddle based on your example

### [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4rg6D/)

Comment: dude I need to check one sec the JsFiddle again but is 404. Thanxs

Comment: I think Jsfiddle has been having some issues. I probably can't recover it.

Comment: @Guillelon it's back. Jsfiddle was attacked by spammers and they blocked a bunch of recent fiddles, but I got them to restore that one.

Answer (score 1):

well previously you can access just becoz it is in scope but right now you done some nesting so you just need to some looping in your view part to get that .

**Something like this may be :**

```
<table data-bind="foreach:myIncomeDeclarationViewModel">
      <tbody data-bind="foreach:$data.incDecDetGroViewModels">
          ...
      </tbody>
   </table>
```

You can also ContainerLess foreach if you looking for something different like :

```
<!-- ko foreach:myIncomeDeclarationViewModel -->
//your table code
<!--/ko-->
```

I hope this solves the riddle .

Comment: I try the first solution you propose but still not getting anything.

Comment: @xdumaine fiddle works fine . if still issue please update your total code .its hard to say with the limited code given .